# Selected option with a select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a select_tag, like this:

```
<%= form_tag orders_path do %>               
           <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
            data-label="Pay by CB"
            data-email="<%= current_user.email %>"
            data-name="Order"
            data-locale=auto>
          </script>
   <!-- url question -->
      <div class="widthfull">
        <p class="question">What's the URL ?</p>
        <div class="widthfull"><%= text_area_tag(:url, "", class: "answer textarea widthfull calcul_checkout", rows:"1") %></div>
      </div>
   <!-- language_ov question -->
     <div> 
      <p class="question">
      What's the language of the video ?
      </p> 
     <div class="flex"> 
      <span class="answer language_ov">></span> 
      <span>
       <%= select_tag(:language_ov, 
         options_for_select([['Français', 'FR'],['Anglais', 'EN']]), 
         class:"answer language_ov calcul_checkout chosen-select")%>
      </span> 
     </div> 
   </div> 
<% end %>
```

But if my user don't re-select the choice by default `params[:language_ov]` is equal to `nil`.

I want to give the default value 'FR' for the `params[:language_ov]` if my user does not select anything.

Here the model validation Request.rb

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Where i'm using the params in the controller

```
.. @request = Request.new(language_ov: params[:language_ov], language_request: language, export_option: params[:export_option]||'no') ..
```

Here the server log (no params for language_ov):

```
Started POST "/orders" for ::1 at 2017-08-07 22:20:22 +0200 Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML'   
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"*************",
"url"=>"www.url.com",
 "video_title"=>"Project name",
 "lengthminutes"=>["6"], "lengthsecondes"=>[""],
 "language_request"=>["EN"],
 "project_comment"=>"",
 "stripeToken"=>"************",
 "stripeTokenType"=>"card",
 "stripeEmail"=>"testemail@gmail.com"}
```

Apparently select_tag don't support selected option. Should i use select methode ? Could you help me to transform my select_tag into select ?

Comment: I'm using `<%= form_tag orders_path do  %>`

Comment: Have you checked the params after sending them?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Yep, i'm using the params[:language_ov] to record an instance of my model video and after the validation it's return nil.

Comment: @Gerry here the complete form code
`<%= form_tag orders_path do %>`
`<%= select_tag(:language_ov, options_for_select([['Français', 'FR'],['Anglais', 'EN']], selected: 'FR'), class:"answer language_ov calcul_checkout chosen-select")%>`
`<% end>`

Comment: I can't find any error nor can't reproduce the problem, using your code as is (just adding a `submit` button) works just fine. How are checking for `params[:language_ov]`? Can you share the server log after submitting the form? (Edit your question, don't add it as a comment).

Comment: Is there some javascript related to the form? I'm not seeing any submit button, that's why I'm making this question...

Comment: Thank you very much @SebastiánPalma for the edit. I modify my question and add the code of the submit. I'm using the stripe checkout to submit the page.

Comment: Just to be clear, if the user selects "EN" manually i tworks?  Or "FR" manually it works?  You're saying afer validation it returns `nil`... makes me wonder if the problem is model validation.

Comment: Just for information i have a text_area_tag question in the form and it's return the correct params[:url] after validation.

Comment: Yes @SteveTurczyn it's exactly the problem.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I don't think so because there is no restriction and the data type in the database it's string.

Comment: Ok, can you please show the controller, and the validations on the model?  Also post the `text_area_tag` so we can compare how it's implemented.

Comment: If the controller is using strong parameters it may not be allowing the `language_ov` attribute.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I edited  my question :-)

Comment: Try replacing selected: 'FR' by the full array selected: ['Francais','FR']

Comment: @Maxence it's not working (still return nill). Apparently select_tag don't support selected option. Should i use select ?

Comment: As @Gerry suggested, please update your question to show the server log after submitting the form.

Comment: `options_for_select` support `selected` option, the problem seems to be in stripe js that sends the form.

Comment: I edit my question with the server log. You can see there is no params[:language_ov]. When i select manually a choice i have a params[:language_ov].

Comment: I found the problem. I had a javascript to pre-fill the form if a value localStorage was save.  I delete this line and it's working. I will find an other solution to save the form and pre-fill the form when the user come back. Do you have an idea to do it ? 

`$("#language_request").val(localStorage.language_request);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had a javascript to pre-fill the form if the user already start to complete the form before. I stock the data with the localStorage variable. So when a user arrive on the page i check if the localStorage exist. And this was the problem because it's rewrite the selected value every time. I add a condition to execute this line (and it's working). I will find an other solution to save the form and pre-fill the form when the user come back. `$("#language_request").val(localStorage.language_request);`